# Laravel Collection->toArray() - KEEP null values

Tags: php, laravel

I've been searching for a way to convert a Laravel Collection to an array and KEEP null values.
However, everything I see is how to ignore null values.

**Is there a straight forward way of keeping null values when converting a Collection to an array that I'm overlooking?**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `$collection->toArray()` should keep null values by default. If you have issues please clarify your use case, code and what issues you are having

Comment: Thank you! There was a filter hidden in the controller that stripped the null values from the collection just before casting to an array. My bad. Thank you though!